# Fitting a bivariate or multivariate weibull distribution to observations in R

Tags: r, model-fitting, weibull

I'm looking to fit a **bivariate Weibull distribution** to my observations. I'm considering writing this myself but before starting I just want to check if anyone has come across a r-package including this functionality or similar.

I'm considering using the method proposed in this paper to estimate the parameters in the density function using maximum likelihood estimation: http://doi.org/10.18187/pjsor.v5i2.120

I'm already using the `fitdistrplus` package for univariate Weibull distribution fitting, but this only shows the marginal cases for a joint distribution. My observations include likely correlated data for two separate variables. The marginal distributions follow Weibull shapes though, which is why I feel confident that a bivariate Weibull distribution would be applicable.

Comment: I guess you already found http://www.real-statistics.com/distribution-fitting/fitting-weibull-regression/ -  there are quite some traps when you try to do it yourself, believe me. I tried doing that years ago...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this might already have an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346249/fitting-weibull-distribution-in-r

Comment: On 2nd thought, the linked stats-post might not help you since it deals with univariate Weibull distribution. Nevertheless, you might re-post the question on that site.

Comment: Thanks, B--rian! It's fairly easy to find ways in R to fit univariate Weibull distributions, but I haven't found any for multivariate. Already tried to post in CrossValidated, but they said it was off topic to ask for tips on r-packages there.